# Is an object involved in this Java “hello world” program?

Tags: oop, java

Given we have java program we declare reference to an object by the declaration such as `String ab=new String`.

How is Java an object-oriented programming language? Where is there an object in this program?

In the following Java code, I can't see any object. I want to know if there is any object used to print the hello message.

```
class a
{ 
  public static void main(String a[])
  {
    System.out.println("hello");
  }
}
```

Comment: The string "hello" is an object from class `String`, also `a` because arrays are also objects

Comment: And keep in mind that few (if any) "object-oriented" languages deal PURELY with objects.  There is (almost) always a need to deal with simple values, call/return stacks, etc.

Comment: 6 answers in 1 minute. Must be a hard question that's why so many pundits are answering it. Kudos!

Comment: @JensG - Not as hard as the other questions they're avoiding.  (And not as boring as the real work they're avoiding.)

Answer (score 5):

If there are `n` command line arguments, then there are `n + 5` objects:

- The string literal `"hello"` is an object.
- The array `a` is an object.
- There is a `String` object for every command line argument passed in to `main` through the `a` array.
- The `System` class, even though there is no instance, has `static` references to 3 objects:  the `out` and `err` `PrintStream`s, and the `in` `InputStream`.

Note that there are no instances of your `a` class.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are few objects involved

The class [System](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) has an object "out" that is an object of type [PrintStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) which is calling its [println](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.String%29) method

```
String a[]
```

a is an object of type: Array (of Strings).

You have your `class a` that even it does not have any attribute or `instance` methods you can still instantiate it, there would be no point since everything it has is a static method (main).

Also you may want to check the features of being object oriented. You have encapsulation, take your main method as an example, you can call it from outside; you have inheritance, your class a, and actually all the classes will inherit at least to the root object class: [java.lang.Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)

```
I want to know if there is any object used to print the hello message.
```

In this case, the object out has a println method implemented that receives a String object to pass the received String in the console.

Comment: Is System.out really an object instance or only a static class? => ok, don't mind, already answered above.

Answer (score 2):

The string `"hello"` is an object. It doesn't have the `new` operator, but this is simply because the `String` class supports the special syntax of creating literals with double quotes.

The `a` array you're declaring in your `main` method is also an object. Any arguments passed are also objects.

`System.out` is also an object (an output stream), one that is initialized in the code of the `System` class.

Answer (score 1):

`a`, `"hello"` and `System.out` are all objects. Most new objects are created with the keyword `new`, but a string literal also creates an object. The object named `a` is created by the Java runtime system to contain the arguments of the program. The object `System.out` is part of the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

`"hello"` is a `String` object. Strings objects can be constructed without expliciet constructor call in Java.

Answer (score 1):

`a`, `System`, `out`, the array passed to main, are all things that descend from java.lang.Object

Answer (score 1):

Nearly everything in Java is an object. In this case, your class 'a' is an object that accepts an array of String objects as a parameter. In the main method, it makes a static call to the System object using another String object as a parameter. To my knowledge, there is no Java without objects.

Answer (score 1):

Just to name a few objects involved in your program:

- `String a[]` is an object;
- `System.out` is an object;
- `"hello"` is an object;

These are the ones you can see. But there's also:

- The `main Thread`;
- `class a`;
- `System`;
- The `ClassLoader`;

And many more.

Of course, it all depends on how you define *involved in the program*.